# Python Loop repeat the process over and over again

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new to web development and i'm testing my site with sending http get request to check on how well my site will handle request. with my code i can send multiple get request, how can i make code send more than multiple request i want the loop to never stop, i mean send the get request over and over again how can i do that.. i am very sorry for my bad English hope u get my question.

```
import time
import datetime
import asyncio
import aiohttp

domain = 'http://myserver.com'
a = '{}/page1?run={}'.format(domain, time.time())
b = '{}/page2?run={}'.format(domain, time.time())

async def get(url):
    print('GET: ', url)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            t = '{0:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
            print('Done: {}, {} ({})'.format(t, response.url, response.status))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    asyncio.ensure_future(get(a)),
    asyncio.ensure_future(get(b))
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to happen over and over, add a [for](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) or [while](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) loop - see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

```py
async def get(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            print('GET: ', url)
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                t = '{0:%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
                print('Done: {}, {} ({})'.format(t, response.url, response.status))
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer sir, this won't affect my run until complete task?

Comment: @Noob you can keep the last 6 lines of code (with `loop.run_until_complete`) the same.